# Pop Up modal only works on first item in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When i click the Details in table row Pop Up modal only works on first item.when i click second row details first one value is open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th>BF/AF</th>
                                    <th>M</th>
                                    <th>A</th>
                                    <th>E</th>
                                    <th>N</th>
                                    <th ng-model="TotalQuantity" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">Total Quantity</th>
                                    <th ng-model="Price" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">Price</th>
                                    <th ng-model="interaction" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">Interaction</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- ngRepeat: product in products --><tr ng-repeat="product in products" class="ng-scope">
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1 AL</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">AF</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">
                                        1

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">24</td>
                                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data="1 AL" ng-click="getProductName(product.ProductID)">Details</a>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty" ng-model="WProductName"> Suppository related warnings</h4>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="firstone">
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/alcohol.png" title="Alcohol">
                                                                <span class="ng-binding">CAUTION</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/pregnancy.png" title="Pregnancy">
                                                                <span ng-model="Pregnancy" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">PROBABLY SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/lactation.png" title="Lactation">
                                                                <span ng-model="Lactation" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/driving.png" title="Driving">
                                                                <span ng-model="Driving" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/kidney.png" title="Kidney">
                                                                <span ng-model="Kidney" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">CAUTION</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/liver.png" title="liver">
                                                                <span ng-model="Liver" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- Modal -->


                                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: product in products --><tr ng-repeat="product in products" class="ng-scope">
                                    <td class="ng-binding">2</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">Practin</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">AF</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">
                                        1

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="ng-binding">26</td>
                                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data="Practin" ng-click="getProductName(product.ProductID)">Details</a>
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty" ng-model="WProductName"> Suppository related warnings</h4>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <div class="firstone">
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/alcohol.png" title="Alcohol">
                                                                <span class="ng-binding">CAUTION</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/pregnancy.png" title="Pregnancy">
                                                                <span ng-model="Pregnancy" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">PROBABLY SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/lactation.png" title="Lactation">
                                                                <span ng-model="Lactation" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/driving.png" title="Driving">
                                                                <span ng-model="Driving" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/kidney.png" title="Kidney">
                                                                <span ng-model="Kidney" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="alcohol">
                                                                <img src="/img/Interaction/liver.png" title="liver">
                                                                <span ng-model="Liver" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-empty">SAFE</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- Modal -->


                                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: product in products -->
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="8" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Total</th>
                                    <th id="right" colspan="3" style="font-size: 1.5em;"><span ng-bind="total" style="margin-left: -1em;" class="ng-binding"></span><span class="ng-binding"> ₹ 50</span></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

DEMO LInk: [**Demo Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3ydpc92z/1/)

Comment: Just change modal ID, Eg: #myModal, #myModal2

Comment: am using repeat function i have only one modelID @Vishnuprasad

Comment: @Vishnuprasad http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/m1q7xsoh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create unique ids and data-target like this using `$index`

```
<td>
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$index}}" data="1 AL" ng-click="getProductName(product.ProductID)">Details</a>
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$index}}" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 1):

When opening a modal it targets an `id` which should always be unique. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Make sure your `data-target="#myModal"` always targets an unique element.

For instance, you could add an index to your loop and append it to the id or the modal.

Comment: Sir This is demo code My orginal code link is http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/m1q7xsoh/1/

Comment: Than, as Nandita Arora Sharma suggests, append the {{$index}} to the id of the element to make it unique. Also, when providing a demo, make sure it works out of the box

Comment: thanks sir @Nandita Arora Sharma answer is correct so i put up vote  for you